# Java opening file

Tags: java, excel, apache, file

In Java, I'm creating an excel file. The excel spreadsheet is being created just fine, but every time it is created, I have to manually search my computer for the file to open it. Is there any command that I can use that will automatically open up the newly created file for the user immediately after the program finishes?

I'm using the apache poi to create the excel file.